# Context sensitive help not working in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, msdn

This seems like a petty question, but this situation is starting to get annoying:

When I'm working in VS 2008 and I want to get context-sensitive help, I highlight the term/keyword/window that I want help on, and I push F1.  It brings up the MSDN help window, but it always gives me a "Page not Found"/broken link on the start, and I have to go to the search page and search on the term that I'm looking for, which is annoying for starters, and sometimes the term is ambiguous and I have to go hunting through tens of different options before I get the right help page.

Anyone else have this problem, or know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem - it doesn't annoy me that much, but I'll be glad if you get a solution all the same!

Comment: @snowcrash09 - see my solution below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution (sort of...)

I switched to using the "Integrated Help Viewer" instead of the "External Help Viewer", and now it works.  I still don't know why the external viewer doesn't work, and I'll give answer credit to whoever can help me set up the external viewer properly...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried messing with your environment-help-online options? You may want to try: "try online first, then local" or "try local only, not online". I don't have this problem, so I can't verify this as a solution, but it's something you may want to try.